# Tittle of post instead of tittle of page in php

Tags: php

How do i make the tittle of post to appear instead of the tittle of page in php site
I have tried putting the php code that pops the tittle of the post but it dint work

Comment: Posts and pages are different entities, what do you mean? If you are in a page it has its own title, if in a post again its own title...

Comment: Could you please provide some more context to explain the issue, and maybe snippets of the code you are using? This will make it easier for others to spot what is wrong and to be able to answer.

Comment: If i share a post from my blog the tittle of the page displays instead of the tittle of the post something like this.  welcome to my blog is the tittle of the single.php page. When i share a post it shows welcome to my blog as the tittle of the post instead of the actual tittle.

Answer (score 0):

To display post title, you could use:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

or alternately, a simple:

```
<?php echo get_the_title(post->$ID); ?>
```

Comment: Where should i place this code at the top of the page or anywhere?

Comment: That depends entirely on where you want it to be visible.

Comment: If you want it to be in browser title bar, then it would go in the <header> section.
If you want it in be visible in the page content, then it would appear as a <h1> or <h2> in the content area.

Comment: i did that but it did not work i want the post tittle to be in the browser tittle bar <img src="<?php echo GW_UPLOADPATH.$get['post_image'];  ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
 <div class="b-bottom"> 
<h5 class="top"><?php echo $get['title_of_post'];  ?></h5>
<p class="sub"><?php echo $get['post_writeup'];  ?></p>